# Is it better practice to use array of JSON objects or separate arrays in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chartist.js

I'm trying to making a bar chart in D3.js and was wondering if it is better  practice to use separate arrays for the data (like an array for x-axis data and another array for y-axis data) or one array of JSON objects (so that the data is more organized), or does it not matter?

I noticed that some javascript chart libraries such as chartist.js use separate arrays. In comparison with D3, does this mean it's okay to keep data separate?

Comment: I think in all d3 examples it has a data object and that data defines the x and y axis range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use array of JSON objects in d3. As you have mentioned in your question, data will look more organized in this data structure. Troubleshooting any errors in data would be difficult while using multiple arrays. Array of objects data structure will also help you in making any further customization to the charts based on data.

Go through this [blog](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/05/28/manipulating-data-like-a-boss-with-d3/) for more details.